# How to Check and Report time taking queries

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mysql-5.6, query-performance

I am using MySQL 5.6.24

How do I capture the queries which are using more system resources?

How do I capture slow running queries and queries not using indexes?

What is the best way to optimize the slow running query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To capture the slow running queries in MySQL, please enable slow query log. Refer the below URL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html

To optimize the queries, you need to get the explain plan of the queries using EXPLAIN command:

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM categories

Detailed documentation is available in the below URL:

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @SQL_RK says,...

Set `long_query_time = 0` to see all queries (but waste a lot of disk space); set to `1` to get a "good enough" picture of the slow queries.

After collecting slow queries for a day, use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the slowlog.  (Or `mysqldumpslow -s t`.)

There is a setting for "queries not using indexes", but I recommend not using it.  It clutters the slowlog with queries that are fast enough on tiny tables.  (If you have a 10-row table, it rarely matters if no index is used.)

For writing good indexes, see my [*cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).  That will get you a long way into "best way to optimize".  Beyond that, go to stackoverflow.com and read those tagged [mysql] [performance]; there are lots of answers there.  Or post your particular situation.  Be sure to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.